# Get Invalid_Signature_V4_Authorization_Header on Compatible S3 Storage

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have a problem to connect my laravel application with an S3 compatible storage. It's hosted by IONOS ([Link to the documentation](https://devops.ionos.com/api/s3/#overview)). Since I need a different base URL, I installed the package [exula/laravel-storage-rados-s3](https://github.com/exula/laravel-storage-rados-s3), which allows me to configure this. I have this configuration in the filesystem.php (Where default values are set in the env function, they are used):

```
'ionos_s3' => [
        'driver' => 'ceph',
        'base_url' => env('IONOS_URL'),
        'port' => env('S3_PORT', 443),
        'scheme' => env('S3_SCHEME', 'https'),
        'tls_verify' => env('S3_TLS_VERIFY', true),
        'timeout' => env('S3_TIMEOUT', 10),
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => env('IONOS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('IONOS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        ],
        'region' => '',
        'bucket' => env('IONOS_BUCKET'),
        'signature_version' => 'v4',
        'version' => 'latest',
        // Set the S3 class to use objects.dreamhost.com/bucket
        // instead of bucket.objects.dreamhost.com
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('IONOS_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),

        'cache' => [
            'store' => 'database',
            'expire' => 18000, #Cache S3 files for 5 hours
            'prefix' => 'cache-prefix',
        ],
```

But I can do what I want. I always get the following error message:

```
Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception

Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3-de-central.profitbricks.com/BUCKET/32/"; 
    AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3-de-central.profitbricks.com/BUCKET/32/` 
    resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>Invalid_Signature_V4_Authorization_Header</Code>
  <Message>Null/Empty S (truncated...) Invalid_Signature_V4_Authorization_Header (client): Null/Empty SigningKey/IsoDate/Signature -     

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error>
      <Code>Invalid_Signature_V4_Authorization_Header</Code>
      <Message>Null/Empty SigningKey/IsoDate/Signature</Message>
      <RequestId>e7bd3a56-7882-1fc1-b68e-0cc47af2c498</RequestId>
      <HostId>FVqRz72LCRTiUvVKH-VpiEXa5EX3643IbdE6Tyu0-FE</HostId>
    </Error>
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any tip online what the error *Invalid_Signature_V4_Authorization_Header* could be due to.
With the access data I can successfully access the bucket via the S3 browser.
I am also surprised that although use_path_style_endpoint is set to false, the request still goes against objects.dreamhost.com/bucket instead of bucket.objects.dreamhost.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I used the package league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (as suggested by Laravel). With the following configuration (.env file) it finally worked:

```
S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[ACCESS_KEY]
S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[SECRET]
S3_DEFAULT_REGION=s3-de-central
S3_BUCKET=[BUCKET_NAME]
S3_URL=https://s3-de-central.profitbricks.com
AWS_URL=https://s3-de-central.profitbricks.com
```